# If f is continuos on an interval, is it then uniformly continuous

Tags: analysis, continuity, proof-verification, uniform-continuity

I have a function, $f$ that is differentiable on $(0,5)$, and I know it is continuous on $(0,5).$  Is it also uniformly continuous on $(0,5)?$

I now know that it is not. Can someone give me a proof of this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$ which is continuous on $(0,5)$.